tensorflow:You are casting an input of type complex64 to an incompatible dtype float32. This will discard the imaginary part
I am trying to define Adam Optimizer for my model. I am using Tensorflow 2.16.1 and Cuda 12.3. I have the following code to define adam optimizer.
optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(ph_learning_rate, beta1 = 0.85, beta2 = 0.98)
tvs = tf.compat.v1.trainable_variables()
gradients, variables = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(net_cost, tvs))
train_step = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

When I run it for compute_gradients it gives me a warning. which is given below
WARNING:tensorflow:You are casting an input of type complex64 to an incompatible dtype float32.  This will discard the imaginary part and may not be what you intended.
WARNING:tensorflow:You are casting an input of type complex64 to an incompatible dtype float32.  This will discard the imaginary part and may not be what you intended.
WARNING:tensorflow:You are casting an input of type complex64 to an incompatible dtype float32.  This will discard the imaginary part and may not be what you intended.
WARNING:tensorflow:You are casting an input of type complex64 to an incompatible dtype float32.  This will discard the imaginary part and may not be what you intended.

The same example was working fine with tensorflow 2.10 but not in tensorflow 2.16.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
I tried to use different versions of tensorflow but it doesn't work after version tensorflow 2.12. I also tried to make the network have only float32 inputs, but the problem with using float32 inputs is, we have to have both parts (real, imaginary) as we have to deal with complex data in our model.
